# Memory inconsistency in C program using Malloc

Tags: c, memory

I'm working with c and dynamic memory, but I'm having issues showing some values in an int ** array

I Used Valgrind see where is the problem, and I know where is it, but I don't really know how to fix it, because the problem has no sense for me.

```
result_s ** greedy(case_s ** cases, int cases_quantity)
{
    int ** case_conteiners;
    int * current_conteirners;
    result_s ** results = malloc(sizeof(result_s*)*cases_quantity);

    for (int i = 0; i < cases_quantity; ++i)
    {
        results[i] = malloc(sizeof(result_s));
        int conteiners_quantity = cases[i]->conteiners_quantity;
        int fuel = cases[i]->fuel;

        int current_fuel = 0;
        int max_conteiner = 0;
        int current_count = 0;
        int case_count = 0;
        current_conteirners = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
        case_conteiners = malloc(sizeof(int*)*256);

        for (int j = 0; j <= conteiners_quantity+1; ++j)
        {
            if (current_fuel < fuel)
            {
                max_conteiner = max_value(cases[i]->conteiners, cases[i]->conteiners_quantity);
                printCurrent(i,max_conteiner);
                current_conteirners[current_count] = max_conteiner;
                current_fuel += max_conteiner;
                current_count++;
            }

            else if (current_fuel >= fuel && current_count <= 2 )
            {

                case_conteiners[case_count] = current_conteirners;

                printf("\n\n HERE IS THE LEAK %d\n\n", case_conteiners[0][1]);
                printf("\n\n HERE IS OK %d\n\n", current_conteirners[1]);

                current_conteirners = malloc(sizeof(int)*20);
                if (j != conteiners_quantity && i-1 != cases_quantity)
                {
                    current_fuel = 0;
                    current_count = 0;
                }
                case_count++;
            }
        }

        if (current_fuel >= fuel && current_count <= 2 )
        {
            case_conteiners[case_count] = current_conteirners;
            case_count++;
        }

        results[i]->conteiners = case_conteiners;
        results[i]->conteiners_quantity = 2;
        results[i]->case_count = case_count;
    }
    return results;
}
```

As you can see, I want to make an array of arrays. I want to put many"current_conteiners" into "case_conteiners".

Almost everything works fine, but case_conteiners[0][1] gives me just a memory number, but case_conteiners[1] gives me the correct value.

EDIT: Here is where I call the function greedy. Cases is an array of case. A Struct with 2 int's and an array int.

```
    results = greedy(cases, atoi(data[1]));
```

Comment: there is no free() in your code

Comment: @chronoxor that must be the problem? I knew that free() is only to free memory

Comment: Whenever you `malloc` memory, you need to later `free`. This also implies that you need to keep pointers to `malloc`'d memory so that you are able to free it. If you "lose" these pointers, you've leaked memory as you no longer have the ability to `free` it.

Comment: please show the places where you call `greedy`...

Comment: Memory leak is when you call malloc without corresponding free(). As you have lots of malloc() and no free() you have lots of memory leaks. Try to create a release() method with free your result_s. And then check it with Vagrant. Each allocation must have a proper free!

Comment: Vagrant? Do you mean Valgrind?

Comment: Ohh, then I misused the concept. Yes, I know, I need to free memory, but my current problem is the memory problem in the array **

Comment: @melpomene yes, you are right.

Comment: Tip: rather than code to the type like `current_conteirners = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);`, code to the size of the referenced object, `current_conteirners = malloc(sizeof *current_conteirners * 2);`.  It is easier to code right, review and maintain.

Comment: Your *observed* problem is probably not a memory leak *per se*, but rather more likely reading an *uninitialized* value or else one accidentally set to something other than you intended.  The print line which gives you the unexpected result is using a hard coded index 0 which may not be the same as the just assigned index case_count, and its unclear if it has necessarily ever previously been assigned.    That you have two `current_conteirners = malloc()` calls in the same loop is however very ugly - your code is at minimum horribly difficult to follow.